# Can the prime gap record of Liu be improved further?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $d$ be the least positive integer such that there are infinitely many distinct prime pairs $\{p,q\}$ with $|q-p|\le d$. The twin prime conjecture is equivalent to $d=2$. In 2013 Yitang Zhang proved that $d\le 7\times10^7$. Maynard improved this to $d\le600$, and a Polymath Team led by Tao obtained further that $d\le 246$.

Quite recently, Chunlei Liu released a prperint [On the gap between primes](http://arxiv.org/abs/2109.03681) in which he modified Maynard's approach to get $d\le 130$.

**Question.** What's the advantage in Liu's modification of Maynard's method?
Can Liu's work be improved further? Can one prove $d<130$ via suitable refinements?

I have not read Liu's paper very carefully. Your helpful comments are welcome!

Comment: The first version of this preprint claimed $d\leq 20$, then it increased to 90, got down to 26, then up to 130. I would wait a little before taking any conclusion.

Comment: I'm curious generally how much effort has gone into improving $246$, even to $245$, say.

Comment: See the following MO thread for certain bottlenecks in improving 246: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392178/possible-contemporary-improvement-to-bounded-gaps-between-primes

Comment: 12 versions of an arxiv preprint claiming big progress on a big conjecture isn't a sign of hope....